# How do I display a table from mysql database inside <option>

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I make so that every table from mysql database is inside an option tag, so the user is able to select one. I hope someone understands how I mean. I know how to view all tables from a database. Grateful for any answer!

Comment: This question is duplicate of thousand others

Comment: @RoyalBg: So... vote to close ;)

Comment: I know but how do I display every table from the database inside it? So every table gets its own <option>, thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but either I am blind or I don't know how to search this question, sorry.

Comment: @user3241442 You know how to query the DB to return the table names, aren't you? So the only thing you need to search is how to print mysql result into drop down. Simply you need to fetch the query that returns the tables, loop over it, and print every single iteration between <option> tags

Comment: Thank you, that is all I needed. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here you only need one single command

```
show tables;
```

If you want specify the database also,

```
show tables from database;
```

Here is the complete PHP code to get table names

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");

echo '<select>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo '<option>'.$row[0].'</option>';
  }
echo '</select>';


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```